# Validate multiple inputs with AJAX/JQUERY and change css of inputs

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I have a form which has multiple inputs with the same name and brackets like:

```
<input name=foo[] id=foo[]/>
```

I'm using the brackets to process the input as array with **PHP** and because the amount of inputs is not fixed.

I'm trying to add some form validation with **AJAX/JQUERY** because each input must contain a value that's already in the database. Once checked I want to change the **CSS** of the input to green if correct and red if wrong.

The AJAX part is working but I can't get **JQUERY** to change the **CSS** of the inputs individually (all inputs are changed);

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<script>
  $(document).change(function() {
    $('input[id="foo[]"]').each(function() {
      $(this).change(validate);
    });
  });

  function validate() { 
    var foo = $(this).val();
    if(foo == "" || foo.length < 4) {
      $('input[id="foo[]"]').css('border', '3px #C33 solid');
    } else {
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "common/check.php",
        data: 'foo='+ foo,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
          if(response == 0) {
            $('input[id="foo[]"]').css('border', '3px #C33 solid');
          } else {
            $('input[id="foo[]"]').css('border', '3px #00FF00 solid');
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `$('input[id="foo[]"]').css('border', '3px solid #C33');`

Comment: its not a good practice to have elements with the same IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code. Try this:

```
 $('input[id="foo[]"]').change(function() {
    var foo = $(this).val();
    var fooInput = $(this);
    if(foo == "" || foo.length < 4) {
      fooInput.css('border', '3px #C33 solid');
    } else {
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "common/check.php",
        data: 'foo='+ foo,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
          if(response == 0) {
            fooInput.css('border', '3px #C33 solid');
          } else {
            fooInput.css('border', '3px #00FF00 solid');
          }
        }
      });
    }
    });
```

Here's the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JudeDuran/c8Swu/).

**NOTE**: avoid having elements with the same ID. It'll cause you headaches as your project expands.

Comment: You should make all element IDs unique.If you want to specify a group of elements, use `CLASS` instead.

Answer (score 1):

try to remove 「"」.

```
$('input[id=foo[]]').css('border', '3px #C33 solid');
```

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question because it was not clear enough. The CSS does changes but in all inputs and I want to change it individually accordingly.